# Recovery factory of a blind computer. No user interaction

Tags: reboot, lubuntu, session

We have a PC with Lubuntu, without monitor, keyboard and mouse. We can only restart it with a button.

We need that when we insert a USB stick and reboot it will automatically start and restore the system **without** user interaction.
The restore should restore the entire operating system with a first "factory" version.

The bios of our MiniPC does not save the configuration with the bootloader from USB as the first choice.

Do you think there is any solution?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details what you mean with "restore the system". Delete everything and install a fresh system? Keep some data and/or configuration? If you have more than one system of this kind, do they need different configuration?

Comment: Are the restore actions scriptable? Does the PC boot from USB? There are USB videocards that are supported under Linux. With a keyboard would perhaps also be an options?

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think there is any solution?

Yes.

Just set up a USB thumb drive to do the restoration. That can be a [CloneZilla live image configured to restore an image unattendely](https://clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=clonezilla-live/doc/05_Preseed_options_to_do_job_after_booting), or it could be very simply a [Ubuntu server installer in automated mode](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall), which you tell to install the `task-lxde-desktop` package, to get you basically a Lubuntu (slightly slimmer).

Of course, you will have to make your PC boot from the USB drive – so, either configure that in your UEFI setup interface ("BIOS Setup" is the historical name of that), or since being able to boot from any device is equivalent (actually, mightier) than being `root`, `sudo efibootmgr --bootnext …` might be the easiest way.